# Integrate with summation series present

Tags: integration, definite-integrals, special-functions

Hi I want to integrate the following, but I have difficulty with the summation series in the integral term. Please suggest how to solve it.
[image]

Comment: What is $c$ in the sum? If just a positive integer, then you just have a finite sum.

Comment: you could pull out the summation

Comment: a,b,c are constants.

Comment: How to solve the summation

Comment: then note after Pulling out $1/n!$ you will have a denormalized gamma density

Comment: How do I solve this?